# how can i use function in $message statement in the following code

Tags: php, string, function, email

suppose i have the following php code and i need to use the function named `any_function` in the string named `$someotherthing`, how can i use it, please help??? and also can i use the string (`$something`) inside the function in `$someotherthing`...

```
<?php

function any_function(){
   $something = "something";
}

$someotherthing="need to use the above function here, how can i?";

?>
```

my actual code which i need to use is as follows, i need to use the `visitor_country()` function in `$message`

```
<?php
$fullName=$_REQUEST['fullName'];
$phnNumber=$_REQUEST['phnNumber'];
$enquery=$_REQUEST['enquery'];
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
function visitor_country()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = "Unknown";
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
    {
        $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
    }

    return $result;
}

 $to="digibeem@gmail.com";
   $subject = "Contact Us form Details";
   $message = "\nFull Name : ".$fullName."\n Phone Number:".$phnNumber."\n General Enquiry : ".$enquery."\n IP Address : ".$ipaddress."\n Country: visitor_country() ";
   $from="dbedu@digibeem.com";
    @mail($to,$subject,$message,"From:$from");
    @header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it like the other variables:

```
$message = "\nFull Name : ".$fullName."\n Phone Number:".$phnNumber."\n General Enquiry : ".$enquery."\n IP Address : ".$ipaddress."\n Country: " . visitor_country();
```

Comment: sorry sir, but i am really new in php, so are you trying to say me to use it like this `".visitor_country()."` ? Please reply as soon as you can....

Comment: Yes i do. `"sometext" . your_function() . " other text"`

Comment: just last question sir, do i need to enclose it in inverted commas?

Comment: If you meen these `'`: You needn't.

Comment: i meant `"` `"` these

Comment: Do it like i showed it to you in my answer. This will do just fine.